# Is there any differences in react hook with set multiple states?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to use hooks with multiple states.

```
const [val, setVal] = useState({
    first: 0,
    second: 0,
    third: 0,
  });

 //first method
  const change = () => {
      // first method
    setVal({
      ...val,
      first: val["first"] + 1,
      second: val["second"] + 1,
      third: val["third"] + 1,
    });
    
      // second method
    setVal((data) => ({
      ...data,
      first: val["first"] + 1,
      second: val["second"] + 1,
      third: val["third"] + 1,
    }));
  };
```

here is my example code.
Both the first and second methods have the same results.

I know, In React Docs, Second Method is recommended. But i think if i use first method, i can save one function call.
 so **why react recommend second method and what is the main differences between first and seconds**.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call "setVal" fast enough, there is chance that accessing val would get incorrect value. If you pass function to the setter, data would be in correct state, so incrementing self should be like this:

```
// data is previous state here
setVal((data) => ({
      ...data, // This is unnecessary as you overwrite all of the values
      first: data["first"] + 1,
      second: data["second"] + 1,
      third: data["third"] + 1,
}));
```

I would also recommend using useReducer in case there are multiple state values.

## EDIT:

Here is example of broken setState (click multiple times)
https://codesandbox.io/s/use-state-broken-0q994
Changing to this

```
setCount((count) => count + 1);
```

Would fix the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!!! I can understand! but i have one more questions.  Am i  doing a function call because of the possibility of accessing incorrect values? I'd like to take a closer look, so can I know a reference or something?

Comment: Thank you!! i can understand why!! your example helps a lot !!